# Calling a dynamic namespaced Class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

this is my first time using PHP OOP and Namespacing. I tried to load the class dynamically but I always got an error. `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function App\Controllers\DefaultController() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\Core\Router.php:20`

I autoload and put namespace (PSR-4) with Composer. I want to create my own MVC before moving on to framework.

`test\app\Core\Router.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use App\Controllers\ErrorController;

class Router
{
    protected $controller;
    protected $action;
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->parseURL();

        if(file_exists(APP_CTRL . $this->controller . ".php"))
        {
           //this is the problem.. the ErrorController() below works fine...
            $class = "App\Controllers\\" . $this->controller;
            $class();
        }
        else
        {
            $error = new ErrorController();
            $error->error_404();
        }
    }

    protected function parseURL()
    {
        $request = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

        if(!empty($request))
        {
            $url = explode('/', $request);

            $this->controller = isset($url[0]) ? ucfirst($url[0]) . 'Controller' : 'DefaultController';
            $this->action = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : 'index';
            unset($url[0], $url[1]);
            $this->params = !empty($url) ? $url : [];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->controller = 'DefaultController';
            $this->action = 'index';
        }
    }
}
```

As for my controller.

`test\app\Controllers\DefaultController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class DefaultController extends Basecontroller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hi from Default';
    }
}
```

Tried using this [Calling a class in a namespace by variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704687/calling-a-class-in-a-namespace-by-variable-in-php) but it's not working

Already checked this: https://coderwall.com/p/kiz5nq/instantiating-a-namespaced-php-class-dynamically and https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-dynamically-invoke-a-class-method-in-php

Comment: What are you expecting the line `$class();` to do?

Comment: If for example the user access my site `example.com` it should load the Default Controller and show the info inside `index` from that controller.

Comment: Have you tried something like `$controller = new $class();  $controller->index();`?

Comment: As it said above try to instantiate your controller by using [`new`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) keyword: `$controller = new $class; $controller->someAction();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the lines...

```
$class = "App\Controllers\\" . $this->controller;
$class();
```

The second line is just trying to call a function with your class name.  Instead you need to create a new instance of the class..

```
$controller = new $class();
```

You can then call whatever method in the class as normal...

```
$controller->index();
```